# how to append anchor tag into parent of div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html code is:

```
<div title="test" class="xyz">Tesing</div>
```

I want it to look like:

```
 <a href='#'> <div  title="test" class="xyz">Tesing</div></a>
```

How to do it using JavaScript?

Comment: Anchors around block level elements are valid in HTML5.

Comment: yes.. I agree with your comment!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously said by Curt, your example is not valid. You should have div with text and surround text with 'a' tag.

You can use jQuery method `.wrapInner()` ([jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/))

You can do it with a simple line :

```
$('.xyz').wrapInner($('<a href="#" />'));
```

jsFiddle is you want to try it :

> http://jsfiddle.net/8vbXw/

Comment: @userJonnyDeff I have done it for you :) .wrapInner() function is new to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than putting the link outside of the div, I would recommend putting it nested inside.

Otherwise this would be invalid HTML.

Therefore your result would be:

```
<div title="test" class="xyz"><a href='#'>Tesing</a></div>
```

This can be done by doing:

```
$(function(){
    $(".xyz").html("<a href='#'>" + $(".xyz").html() + "</a>");
});
```

You can then style the anchor tag so that the whole div is selectable:

```
.xyz a
{
   display:block;
}
```